# Django send_mail() in GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I want a logged in user to be able to send a copy of the model object they created that has been saved in the database. Am using the get(pk=id) to recognize the particular one the user wants to send. The problem is, the send_mail() doesn't recognize the recipient email (to).

```
   @login_required
    def email_query(request, id):
        history = Carloan_form.objects.get(pk=id)
        subject = 'Nigerian Loan Calculator Query e-mail'
        from_email = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
        email = request.user.email
        to = "email"
        send_mail(subject,get_template('carloan/loancalc-query.txt').render(Context({'history':history})),\
                 from_email,[to], fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponse('sent')
```

## Update

```
@login_required
def email_query(request, id):
    history = Carloan_form.objects.get(pk=id)
    subject = 'Nigerian Loan Calculator Query e-mail'
    from_email = 'ajibike.ca@gmail.com'
    email = request.user.email
    send_mail(subject,get_template('carloan/loancalc-query.txt').render(Context({'history':history})),\
             from_email,[email,], fail_silently=False)
    return HttpResponse('/history_query_sent/')
```

Just decided to pass the email straight into the send_mail() and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you've set `to` to the string `"email"`. I doubt that is what you wanted to do.

Why not pass the `email` variable directly into the `send_mail` call?

Comment: And that was exactly what i did just before i saw your reply and it worked. Was just trying to follow the Django definition of send_mail(). Thanks